# Use html file for geting all html content as string into variable in jinja2

Tags: python-2.7, flask

Pass HTML file for getting all HTML content as a string into jinja2.Markup, like

```
content = jinja2.Markup('python/pythonIntro.html') // I know it is wrong...
```

Here I need to pass file name and markup all contents. How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, You can use this code for find required file from you environment and also pass path of file which return all contents of file.

```
from jinja2 import Markup, PackageLoader, Environment

def include_file(name):
    #env = jinja2.environment
    return Markup(loader.get_source(env, name)[0])

loader = PackageLoader(__name__, '')
env = Environment(loader=loader)
env.globals['include_file'] = include_file

print env.get_template('templates/<file.ext>').render() # as per address of file structure
```